# How to keep a bone on an object (Ex. A hand on a table) when moving an inverse kinematically rigged model?

Tags: animation, bones, bone.constraints

Looking to see if anyone knows how to keep a bone stationary on an object (Ex. A hand on a table) when moving an inverse kinematically rigged model?

Issue:
Have a model that is sitting at a table (with hands on the table) and then stands up (with hands still on the table). Once the hip bone is moved from a sitting position to a standing position, the hand bones move along with the model. Trying to keyframe the hand bones does aid a little, but essentially the hand bones bounce around from one keyframe to another (since they are not stationary). Additionally, have tried to create empties with hand bone child-of constraints to no avail.

Note:
It would be great if there is a simple solution that doesn't involve rigging (Ex. Making a forward kinematic rig). Haven't really weight painted and not sure if automatic weights would distort the model. However, any answer would suffice.

Thanks in advance

[image: An inverse kinematic model with hand bones located on table.]